# OPenID Connect : What to do with the access token

Tags: session, openid, openid-connect

I have a few questions on the correct usage of the access token received from the token endpoint.

1. Where should I store the token? Ideally I would like to store it in a cookie so that I can have stateless sessions which will help me in scaling. But will keeping the access token in a cookie be a security vulnerability ?
2. For every subsequent request the client makes, should I introspect the access token every time ? **Introspecting the token every time looks to be a significant overhead.** The alternative I see is to create a session and keep the user authenticated as long as a session is maintained. However I think this is ugly because :

   - I lose 'statelessness'
   - If the user logs off from the identity provider, I would not know as the session is still maintained at my end

Please let me know if my understanding is correct on the points I wrote and what would be the correct solution to these 2 problems.

Comment: Cookie is fine as it's over HTTPS, you can use local storage as well. Add token header in every request is not overhead. It's OK

Comment: Thanks. By overhead I meant introspecting the token for every request. To introspect I will have to hit the introspection endpoint every time. That is just doubling the http requests.

Answer (score 1):

**Q :  Where should I store the token?**

Somewhere safe.! Which can only be accessed by the client to which token issued.

All the time when you transmit access token, you must use TLS. This is mandated by RFC6749 - [10.3.  Access Tokens](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.3)

> Access token credentials MUST only be transmitted using TLS

**Q : For every subsequent request the client makes, should I introspect the access token every time ?**

Depends on your application. If you cannot maintain a session, then you can use a temporary cache. For example this can be implemented in a Java filter which comes before your endpoint. If cache does not hold validity details for the access token comes with a request, then you should use introspection to validate it.

But be mindful about caches. Implementation depends heavily on your application. Also, you can face with invalidation issues. You should know about access token lifetime to invalidate cache entry.

**Q : If the user logs off from the identity provider, I would not know as the session is still maintained at my end**

Openid conenct define session management spec. which gives you options to identify end user session information from OpenID provider. But to use these, OP should support the spec implementations. Check the spec from [here](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html)

Comment: 1. Can I really consider cookies safe ? Because access to cookies will mean complete access.
2 and 3. I think I get the introspection point. But caching the sessions will result in the issue of single signoff. Also since the authentication server maintains the sessions, I believe I should avoid creating them at the application end.

Comment: @abhinavpandey well, it depends. If you are using TLS and HTTP only cookie then you avoid interception and XSS attacks. Also, you can make it a secure cookie so that cookie won't get transmitted on non TLS enabled channels (insecure channels). Storing access token in a cookie is similar to a session cookie.

Comment: Caching I mentioned was about access token caching. This is to minimise overhead of validations and introspection calls.